# Does Flame Blade count as a weapon for Extra Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, weapons

Assume you are a Druid 3 / Ranger 5.

Can you attack twice with the Flame Blade when you use Extra Attack?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### No, you can't

> You can use your action to make a melee spell
> attack with the fiery blade. On a hit, the target takes
> 3d6 fire damage. — PHB p. 242

The rub is that it describes it as a *melee spell attack*, vs. a melee attack. As such its in the same category as Inflict Wounds and other touch spells as a distinct action vs. a regular Attack action.

***Extra Attack* only triggers when you make the Attack action**

Even if you interpret melee spell attacks as being one and the same as melee attacks, the simple fact remains that *Extra Attack* only triggers when the Attack action is taken.

Comment: @András There are no subsets of actions. The spell creates a new use for your action, it doesn't use the Attack Action.

Comment: This answer was bothering me, in that if you use the weapon as an attack action, it would be used twice as an improvised weapon. And then I realized that perhaps the concentration aspect of the spell precludes doing multiple attacks with it.

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation. What "melee spell attack" stipulates is that you use your spellcasting ability instead of your strength to resolve the attack. A melee spell attack is still an attack action (nothing in the rules states that it is not) and thus, I would interpret that as it being compatible with a extra attack.

Comment: @max attack action is not a general class, encompassing anything and everything that is an attack, "Attack action" (its capitalized as such in the text) is an action you can take on your turn that gives you a melee attack. If you think your answer is correct, submit it, don't comment on mine.

Comment: I would recommend adding a couple of comparisons to the other weapon based spells in the PHB. Examples include: Greenflame Blade, which uses an extant weapon and the wording follows suit. Thorn Whip, which conjures a whip that isn't a weapon and also uses the wording *melee spell attack.* The specific wording of Shillelagh and how the weapon doesn't make melee spell attacks, it still makes melee attacks. Ice Knife uses the wording *ranged spell attack* and clearly isn't sling or bow ammunition. Oh, and Spiritual Weapon has the best example IMO - Just some reinforcement for your answer.

Answer (score 8):

> You can use your action to make a melee spell 
>   attack with the fiery blade.

This creates a new type of action in addition to the 9 or so enumerated in the PHB, if you use it you are not using the Attack action upon which all multiple attack features rely.

Answer (score -3):

Flame blade is similarly powerful to Shadowblade and Spiritual Weapon.  It is arguably weaker than Shadowblade, because it levels slower, it's on the druid, doesn't provide advantage in low light, and it doesn't have a thrown option.  If a player wanted to use a similar description  with this spell I think this would be highly reasonable and fair for your table top:

'This magic sword lasts until the spell ends. It counts as a magical flaming scimitar melee weapon. If you let go of the blade, it disappears, but you can evoke the blade again as a bonus action.

The conjured melee weapon deals 3d6 psychic damage on a hit.  For the duration you may use your spell casting ability instead of strength or dexterity for the attack and damage rolls of melee attacks using that weapon.'

This is how Solasta handled it, and I think it's good but also not overly impressive.

Comment: Your answer is a house rule suggestion which is okay if it also accompanies the actual rules/ruling question, so please include that in your answer as well. Also welcome, please take the [tour].

Answer (score -5):

You cast a spell when you summon the blade in to existence.

Melee "spell" attack is in reference to what mod you **can** use.

If you chose to use your Wisdom mod treat it as a spell attack.

Then the answer would be no, you do not.

If you use your dexterity or strength mod like you would a normal sword swing

Then you are going thru a physical attack motion and that should  trigger any

thing swinging a normal "flaming scimitar" would.

Then the answer would be yes, you get your second attack.

Note, there is nothing in the spell description baring you from making normal attacks with your brand new flaming scimitar.

Comment: The idea that you can use the Flame Blade as a normal weapon is interesting and while not explicitly supported by the spell certainly isn't ruled out either. Refocusing this answer on that portion (How the spell creates a fiery blade, and how well it does provide a new action that doesn't rule out using your normal actions to use the blade) could make this a very interesting answer. You also may want to address what sort of damage using Fiery Blade in this way may do, since the 3d6 is only listed for the special action. Perhaps basing damage off the description making it similar to a scimitar?